Table name containing a parameter based on the current date
Please tell me how I can create a table name containing a parameter based on the current date in Impala.
create table my_scheme.my_table_${mm} as ...
@set mm = 10 works, but how can I set parameter mm as month(now())?
@set mm = month(now()) doesn't work.
